# React Native : Show parent component after closing a modal on child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two components a Parent Component (`App.js`) and a Child Component (`Logitem.js`)

The parent component contains an array of child component and passes props to it.

The child component has a modal which is invoked upon clicking on a text element inside the child component.

The modal has a delete button which performs a delete operation on db.

All the above are working fine.

After the delete operation is performed I would like to show the parent component (aka) `App.js` but as of now the UI is still showing the modal on the child component.

How do we achieve that ?

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ScrollView, Modal, DatePickerIOS } from 'react-native';
import {
  dropLogsTable,
  createLogsTable,
  getProfileHeightStandardfromDB,
  saveLogsRecord,
  populateDummyLogs,
  getLogsRecords,
  getLogsRecordsFromDB,
  neverendingmethod,
  getLogsDetailsforSaveDelete
} from '../src/helper';
import { Spinner } from '../src/Spinner';
import  Logitem  from '../src/Logitem';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {

    allLogs:{
                rows:{
                            _array:[{logstringdate:''}]
                        }

            },
    profileobject: {profileheight: 100, profilestandard: "XYZ"},
    showspinner: true,
    count:0


  };


  componentDidMount() {
     this.fetchProfileData();
     this.getAllLogs();
}


renderSpinner() {
  if(this.state.showspinner) {
  return <Spinner size="small" />;
  }
  else {
  //return this.state.allLogs.rows._array.map(ae => <Text>{ae.bmi}</Text>);
  return this.state.allLogs.rows._array.map(
    (ae) =>  (
              <View
                  key={ae.logdate}
              >
              <Logitem

                      logstringdate={ae.logstringdate}
                      bmi={ae.bmi}
                      weight={ae.metricweight}
                      logdate={ae.logdate}


                      />
              </View>
    )

  );

  }

}


  async fetchProfileData() {
    console.log('Before Profile Fetch');
    const result = await getProfileHeightStandardfromDB();
    console.log('After Profile Fetch');
    console.log('Height : '+result.profileheight);
    console.log('Standard: '+result.profilestandard);
    this.setState({profileobject:result}); //Line Y
    return result; //Line X

  }

  async getAllLogs() {
    console.log('Before All Logs Fetch');
    const allLogs = await getLogsRecordsFromDB();
    console.log('After All Logs Fetch');
    console.log('Spinner State ==>'+this.state.showspinner);
    if(allLogs != null)
    {
    this.setState({allLogs, showspinner: false});
    console.log('After async spinner state ==>'+this.state.showspinner);
    console.log(allLogs);
    }
    return allLogs;
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
              {this.renderSpinner()}
      </ScrollView>
  );


  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  top: {
    width: '100%',
    flex: 1,
  },
  bottom: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Modal, DatePickerIOS, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import {
  deleteSelectedRecordDB
} from '../src/helper';
import { Spinner } from '../src/Spinner';


export default class Logitem extends Component {

  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);
    const { logstringdate, bmi, weight, logdate } = this.props;

  }

state = {
    selecteddate: '1',
    selectedweight: this.props.weight,
    showmodal: false,
    date: new Date(86400000 * this.props.logdate),

  }

  async deleteSelectedRecord(){
     console.log('Delete clicked');
     console.log('this.state.selecteddate ==>' + this.state.selecteddate); //LINE X
     const result = await deleteSelectedRecordDB(this.props.logdate);
     console.log('deleteSelectedRecord after');
     console.log('result ==> '+ result);
     return result;

  }

  setModalVisible = (visible) => {
    this.setState({showmodal: visible});
  }

  onWeightClick = () => {
      this.setState({ selecteddate: this.props.logdate, showmodal: true }, () => {

        console.log('Value in props==>' + this.props.logdate);
        console.log('The selecteddate in the state ==> ' + this.state.selecteddate);
      });

    }

    onDateChange(date) {
        this.setState({
          date: date
        });
      }

render() {

  return (

    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
    <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.showmodal}
          onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
          >
         <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
                 <DatePickerIOS
                   date={this.state.date}
                   mode="date"
                   onDateChange={(date) => this.onDateChange(date)}
                   style={{ height: 100, width: 300 }}
                 />
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 22, borderColor: '#ddd', borderWidth: 5 }}>
                 <TextInput
                   returnKeyType="done"
                   keyboardType='numeric'
                   style={{
                     height: 40,
                     width: 60,
                     borderColor: 'gray',
                     borderWidth: 1,

                   }}
                   onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ selectedweight: text })}
                   value={this.state.selectedweight.toString()}
                 />
                <Text>KG</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Delete"
                    onPress={this.deleteSelectedRecord.bind(this)}
                    style={{ marginTop: 200 }}
                />

         </View>

        </Modal>
              <View style={styles.headerContentStyle}>
                    <Text>{this.props.logstringdate}</Text>
                    <Text>{this.props.bmi}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                    <Text onPress={this.onWeightClick}>{this.props.weight}</Text>
              </View>
    </View>
  );

}
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop:10,
  },
  thumbnailContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row'

  },
  headerContentStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Simple in deleteSelectedRecord function call setModalVisible(false)